# Eikonel equation on circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi_t(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi_t\right)^2$$
For $\psi_t:S^1\to\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to expand in Fourier
$$\psi_t(x)=\sum_n a_n(t)e^{inx}$$
And got
$$2a_n'(t)=\sum_k a_{n-k}(t)a_k(t)$$
But I have no ideia how to solve it.

Comment: It's not really an eikonal equation, it's hyperbolic - if you let $v=\partial\psi/\partial x$ then $\partial v/\partial t = v\partial v/\partial x$, a nonlinear wave equation (which suggests using method of characteristics to solve).